# Rule-specific scattergather directive

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs, wildcard-expansion

In the Snakemake documentation on [defining scatter gather rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#defining-scatter-gather-processes), the `scattergather` directive is set globally. Is it possible to set the specific value for each rule? For example, `rule a` splits into 8, and `rule b` split into 4?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define custom names for specific scatter-gather processes, e.g.:

```py
scattergather:
    split_a=8,
    split_b=4,
```

Where you would use `scatter.split`, use `scatter.split_a` or `scatter.split_b`, and similarly replace `gather.split`. A full example `Snakefile` is provided [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1798).

<s>Edit: note that there is currently a bug in `snakemake` as of `7.12.0`) that doesn't handle this case properly. There is a fix available in [this PR](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1799), but it might take some time before it's integrated into the main version.</s>

Edit: to use this feature, make sure that your `snakemake` is updated to version [`7.12.1`](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1803) or later.